# Photo Album Software

Tags: multimedia, photo-management, iphoto

I call to the power of the community for some tips and information on the existence of Photo album software available.

I used iPhoto for many years but now my albums are getting to large and unmanageable for my Mac laptop. (This is a well known side effect from having children).

**Prerequisites:**

- Need to be able to open/convert iPhoto albums
- LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with a photo manager called Shotwell. It's a pretty nice photo manager, as far as I have seen it.

It isn't able to import iPhoto databases natively, but people have made scripts to run on Ubuntu that, when given the path to the iPhoto Library and the path to the Shotwell database, can import the Library.

Remember, these don't actually move any images. Just like iPhoto, Shotwell will only have the path of where to look.

Scripts:
https://github.com/gaetronik/iPhotoShotwell
https://github.com/fasaxc/shotwell-iphoto-import

Comment: Thank you for the scripts! I am currently unable to use Shotwell, but i have it in reserve.

Comment: Why can you not use it?

Comment: I am running a beta system and there is a bug in the menu system. And i want something a bit more advanced for the long run. If you are very interested: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317913

Comment: @IzznogooooD Ah. Well, you should definitely report that bug. I also believe that, once you import to Shotwell, you'll have an easy time importing that to other programs.

Answer (score 4):

There are several photo album software that I introduce here:

1. Shotwell
2. Picasa For Linux
3. F-Spot
4. Digikam
5. XnView MP

XnView MP is the enhanced version of XnView Classic. It is a powerful cross-platform media browser, viewer and converter. Compatible with more than 500 formats.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestions, i will have a closer look. Do you know of the bat if any of these have network features. Like me and my wife sharing access to the same photo library ideally cross platform, but just linux is also fine.

Comment: Digikam was nice but requires KDE so i went with Shotwell and Scripts.